# Vue error using Vueify Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, gulp

I am new to Vue and have managed to get a sample app working using gulp, vueity and typescript.

I am putting the main parts of the code to demonstrate whats going on and the issue I am having

Menu.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Menu from './menucomponent.vue'
new Menu().$mount('#menu');
```

MenuComponent.ts

```
import { Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'
import TestComponent from './test.vue'

@Component({
    components: {
        TestComponent 
    }
})
export default class Menu extends Vue {}
```

MenuComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container menu">
    <TestComponent/>
    </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts" src="./menucomponent.ts"></script>
```

Test.vue

```
<template>
<h1>hi</h1>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component,Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
@Component({
})
export default class test extends Vue{}
</script>
```

Gulp method to compile ts and vue

```
gulp.task('compile-vue', function () {
    // we define our input files, which we want to have
    // bundled:
    var paths = {
        browserifyEntries: [
            'menu.ts'
        ],
        dependencies: ['']
    };
    // map them to our stream function
    var tasks = paths.browserifyEntries.map(function (entry) {
        console.log('Compiling ' + entry);
        return browserify({ entries: ["ScriptsSrc/vue/" + entry] })
            .external(paths.dependencies)
            .plugin(tsify)
            .transform(vueify)
            .transform(babelify, { presets: ["es2015"], extensions: [".tsx", ".ts"] })
            .bundle().on('error', swallowError)
            .pipe(source(entry))
            .pipe(rename({
                extname: '.js'
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/scripts'));
    });
    // create a merged stream
    return es.merge.apply(null, tasks);
});
```

**Issue**
I am able to do everything I need in the MenuComponent and it all goes well and works.

But due to the growing codebase I wanted to split it up into components like the  and as soon as I attempt that I get an error from Vue as follows

[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

I am only using gulp as I wish to avoid webpack and introduce another tool into the build.

Would appreciate any ideas about what i might be missing.

Comment: You're not registering `TestComponent` in `MenuComponent.ts`. Also, where is `CategoryItem` coming from? `Test.vue` doesn't import the decorator or extend `Vue`, either.

Comment: @btl Actually because the actual code is long i copied it and missed some of the details out, but have edited. .

Comment: `Test.vue` is still missing the decorator and Vue imports.

Comment: Again its all there in the code itself but edited again

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is with the class name in `Test.vue` and the corresponding import statement in `MenuComponent.ts`.

Try changing the class name to this:

```
export default class TestComponent extends Vue{}
```

which would align with the expected exported default here:

```
import TestComponent from './test.vue'
```

Or change the above import to:

```
import test from './test.vue'
```

and update the component registration:

```
components: {
    test
}
```

Comment: That did not actually work as console.log(test) is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help someone else using typescript/vue/gulp.

After many many hours i have found a solution which seems to work for now its modifying the code as follows:

Menu.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Menu from './menucomponent.vue'
import TestComponent from './test.vue'
new Menu({components:{TestComponent}}).$mount('#menu');
```

It seems for some reason it injects the component at this level and can remove the @Component() from MenuComponent.

I am sure there is a simple fix to register the component inside the MenuComponent but for now this works fine.